# Gradient on Button not filling entire space of button - HTML

Tags: html, extending, gradient

I have this piece of code that displays a gradient on a button

```
<button
    type="button"
    style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, red 50%, blue 50%);"
    class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"
></button>
```

The problem is this is the result (screenshot)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvdA0.png

I want red on top and blue on the bottom, but to extend to the very bottom, you can see that the colors randomly switch at the bottom. How do I prevent this? - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go... Note the `!important`. You need to override Bootstrap's CSS.

For your Style Sheet:

```
.btn {
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, red 50%, blue 50%) !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}
```

Or For Inline:

```
style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, red 50%, blue 50%); background-repeat: no-repeat !important;"
```